# How to AFNetworking in Static Library and main application in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, callback, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking in static library, and also using another set of files of AFNetworking in main application.

```
@interface LGHTTPRequestResponse : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
```

I have same code, but two different bunch of files and instances. But I get callback of library HTTP requests in main application.

```
[self POST:url parameters:parameters
       success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *task, id responseObject)
```

How it is possible, even though it is static library, I have created two different instances in lib and main application? Why above code runs for both the urls in static lib as well as main application?

After trying too many things, I even changed name of the classes in lib and main application. But behaviour remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what little understanding I have of your question (you're wording is very confusing),

I think you are saying:

1. You have two different sets of AFNetworking files.
2. You expect to be able to reference them separately.

You cant do this.  Once the namespace for AFNetworking has been taken up, the second set of files will overwrite the first, and you can't guarantee which will be imported first.

Either way, it sounds like you are doing something wrong.

Learn about [using cocoapods to install AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) and this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of efforts I solved problem myself. Need to change everything, like not just name of the class, but name of delegate and other data structure. And it worked as expected.